# How to Define Order Relations in Irrational Numbers Compared to $\Bbb N,~ \Bbb Z$, and $\Bbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, order-theory

I'm curious about how order relations are defined among irrational numbers. While the ordering of integers and rational numbers is straightforward, in the sense:

After constructing natural numbers $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ using Peano's axioms, we define the order '$\leq$' using successor function. Once the order defined over $\Bbb N$, we can easily extend the order
in to $\Bbb Z$ in such a way that $a \leq b$ if and only if $b-a \in \Bbb N$. Similarly, we can define the same over $\Bbb Q$ as $$\frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{c}{d} \Leftrightarrow ad \leq bc.$$

But I stuck at the definition of '$\leq$' over irrational numbers.
I'm really interested in understanding the criteria for comparing irrational numbers and consequently in the set $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Which definition of the real numbers are you using?  For example, if you define them as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, $x \le y$ iff there are sequences of rationals $r_n \to x$, $s_n \to y$ with $r_n \le s_n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Union of both rational numbers and irrational numbers.

Comment: The irrational numbers are not generally defined before the real numbers.  Irrational numbers are real numbers that are not rational.

Comment: Continuing Robert's comment.  If reals are "Dedekind cuts" $(L|R)$, then for two real numbers $x_1 = (L_1|R_1), x_2 = (L_2|R_2)$ we define $x_1 \le x_2$ iff $L_1 \subseteq L_2$.

Comment: A better question would be how order is defined on the whole set of real numbers: presumably you would also like to order two numbers when one is rational and the other is irrational.

Comment: Nonetheless, that question is very hard to answer without knowing *what* concept of the real numbers you are working with. If you are assuming axioms for the real numbers as many textbooks do, there would be one answer. You, on the other hand, seem to be working with some particular construction of the real numbers starting with $\mathbb Q$, but *then* the answer would depend on *which* construction you are working with: Dedekind cuts of $\mathbb Q$? or completion of $\mathbb Q$? or something else?

Comment: While defining a Dedekind cut ($L|R$), How can we ensure such an $L$ exists, so that for any rational number $x \in L$ there exists another rational numbers $y \in L$ such that $x \leq y$?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] we define the order $\leq$ using successor function. Once the order defined over $\mathbb{N}$ [...]

I suppose you mean

$x \lt_{\mathbb{N}} y :\iff \exists z(x+succ(z) = y)$

which gives us the c(l)ue ('add something of a positive magnitude') to define the usual ordering on the reals as/by

$x \leq_{\mathbb{R}} y :\iff \exists z(x+z^2 = y)$